# Adding a String to JsonArray

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a JsonArray which I am getting as a result of call to a method and it looks like - `["#group-apiTest2","#group-apiTest3","#group-apiTest4"]`
I want to insert one more string - `"group-apiTest1"` in this JsonArray.
So far I tried this but got a different output then expected.

```
String group1 = "#group-apiTest1";
JsonArray existingArray = ["#group-apiTest2","#group-apiTest3","#group-apiTest4"] //For representation purpose only.
JsonObject jsonRequest = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("tags",
                                Json.createArrayBuilder().add(group1).add(existingArray))
                        .build();
                logger.info("REQUEST - {}", jsonRequest);
```

The output of the logger is -
REQUEST - `{"tags":["group-apiTest",["#group-apiTest2","#group-apiTest3","#group-apiTest4"]]}`
instead of -
REQUEST - `{"tags":["group-apiTest","#group-apiTest2","#group-apiTest3","#group-apiTest4"]}`

Please let me know how to get the expected output. Where am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see what's wrong.
But please try this:

```
JsonObject jsonRequest = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                        .add("tags", Json.createArrayBuilder(existingArray).add(0, group1))
                        .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding string `#group-apiTest1` and array `["#group-apiTest2","#group-apiTest3","#group-apiTest4"]`. That's why you see the result as `["group-apiTest",["#group-apiTest2","#group-apiTest3","#group-apiTest4"]]`

Please try this code logic

```
String group1 = "#group-apiTest1";
JsonArray existingArray = ["#group-apiTest2","#group-apiTest3","#group-apiTest4"];
JsonArrayBuilder builder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
builder.add(group1);
existingArray.forEach(builder::add);
JsonObject jsonRequest = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("tags", builder)
                .build();
```

Since you cannot directly add values to JsonArray you have to create a new builder and add your elements.